# Imagen no reacciona por completo como link

Tags: html

Tengo un menú en una pagina web pero la imagen del logo no reacciona como link por completo, sólo una parte de la imagen reacciona al click. Según yo, es por los divs, pero no sé cómo arreglarlo.

```html
<nav class="top-bar show-for-medium-up" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <a href="index.php" class="logo">
        <img src="img/caguama.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li style="margin-right:15px;"><a class="registrate" href="registrate.php">REGISTRATE</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="sesion" href="login.php">INICIAR SESIÓN</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <ul class="right nav-menu">
      <li><a href="Inicio.php">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active"><a href="quinesomos.html">quines somos</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="soporte.php">SOPORTE</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contacto.php">CONTACTO</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Se supone que cuando le des click en cualquier parte de la imagen debe reedireccionar pero no lo hace

Comment: tu codigo esta bien, lo revisaste, hiciste la prueba con varias imagenes?

Comment: Sin el estilo difícilmente podemos ayudarte. Es muy posible que un `div` esté solapándose con el logo, pero para determinarlo tenemos que ver el css de tu página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funciona bien, o es por lo que cambie la imagen?

```html
<nav class="top-bar show-for-medium-up" data-topbar role="navigation">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <a href="index.php" class="logo"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6qHJTkvAKjmyQZ_zr_tF_ngX7D-N5pl1S8uC6N8t9t7VCa3s7"></a>
                </li>
            <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
            </ul>

            <section class="top-bar-section">
            <!-- Right Nav Section -->
            <ul class="right">
                <li style="margin-right:15px;"><a class="registrate" href="registrate.php">REGISTRATE</a></li>
                <li><a class="sesion" href="login.php">INICIAR SESIÓN</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br>
            <ul class="right nav-menu">
                <li><a href="Inicio.php" >Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="quinesomos.html">quines somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="soporte.php">SOPORTE</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.php">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

deber verificar las clases en tu css, si no tenemos a la vista el codigo css no podremos ayudarte, de igual manera verifica que tus divs abran y cierren y lo que esta dentro de cada div sea lo que debe estar y no esta demas verificr el directorio donde esta tu imagen, puede que estes especificandole mal la ruta, checa si estan al mismo nivel de directorio o si tu carpeta "**img**" esta fuera de esa carpeta, si se encuentra fuera puedes usar **../** para regresarte un directorio, igual cerciorate que este bien la extencion "**.png , .jpg, etc**"

Answer (score -1):

Ya quedó resuelto, cambié la clase del `div`:

```
div="rigth"
```

y quedó perfecto.